# Where to store a JWT Token and user id in a React JS application?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, refresh-token

My application contains React JS in Front End and Fast Api in backend. I am using token Authentication and generating a JWT token and sending back to client and i am storing the JWT Token and user id in Client Side ( Local Storage ) and have to send token alongwith every request

Code

```
export const handleAuthentication = (data) => {
  localStorage.setItem("userID", data.user_id);
  localStorage.setItem("subID", data.user_sub);
  localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
  localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
  localStorage.setItem("is_authenticated", "true");
  localStorage.setItem("session_expired", "false");
  window.location.replace("/success");
};
```

But I have read somewhere that local storage is not secure. Also there are many posts i referred but i am not getting proper approach. Any suggestions would be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie is the best option, simply because you can have much more fine grind control in cookie other than LocalStorage or SessionStorage. Some of them are -

**Expiry**

You can define the lifetime of your cookie

```
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Thu, 31 Oct 2021 07:28:00 GMT;
```

**Restrict Access**

A cookie with the Secure attribute is sent to the server only with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol, never with unsecured HTTP (except on localhost), and therefore can't easily be accessed by a man-in-the-middle attacker

```
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Thu, 21 Oct 2021 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

**SameSite attribute**

The SameSite attribute lets servers require that a cookie shouldn't be sent with cross-origin requests (where Site is defined by the registrable domain), which provides some protection against cross-site request forgery attacks (CSRF).

```
Set-Cookie: mykey=myvalue; SameSite=Strict
```

https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where should i set the cookie? In the back end or in the front end ? And should it contain JWT Token and user id in my case?

Comment: You can store your JWT in cookie of your front end (React) app, and can use axios global variable to set it to the header. In this way you do not need to attach it to every request you made from the UI

Comment: So in a response from the server i should attach the cookie right? so how will get set in the front end? Automatically?

Comment: When you do the successful login you will receive a JWT token, store the token to a cookie in your react app

Comment: @AaminKhan I am following the same method that you've suggested, but I have 1 doubt. I use the httpOnly flag in my cookie that I send from server to client. I read that it protects against XSS attacks. So if httpOnly flag is set, how do I access my jwt on the front-end (client-side) ? I can use `axios.deaults.headers.common` to set it after I get my response on first login. But is the user refreshes or opens the app in new tab, I loose that header and the user is signed out.

Comment: @HarshitTrehan I have the same problem. did you find any solution?